# Using a var to complete watir agent

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, google-chrome, watir-webdriver

I am working on a way to share a Ruby program. This is my test code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
require 'google_drive'

@browsertype =""
@name =""
@champsname = ""
@date = DateTime.now

file = File.exists?("temp.txt")
if file == true
   input = IO.read("temp.txt")
   input_hash = Hash[*input.gsub(/"/,"").split(/\s*[\n=]\s*/)]
     browsertype = input_hash.shift
     name  = input_hash.shift
     champsname  = input_hash.shift


  @browsertype = browsertype[1]
  @name  = name[1]
  @champ = champsname[1]

end
if file == false
f = File.new("temp.txt", "w")

  # processing
    puts "What browser will you be using? "
      browsertype = gets
      f.write("browser = :")
      f.write(@browsertype)
    puts  "What is your name? "
     name = gets
       f.write("name = ")
       f.write(@name)
     puts "what is your champs name"
      champsname = gets
       f.write("champion = ")
       f.write(@champsname)


     @browsertype = browsertype
     @name  = name
     @champ = champsname

   end
     puts @browsertype
     puts @name
     puts @champ
     puts @date

#@b = "Watir::Browser.new :"+@browsertype

 agent = Watir::Browser.new
 @b = agent+@browsertype

#b = @b

#b.goto 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AncPM9_7wL02dHVaSWg5eklfYW5jdTE3NGtJSGJPb3c'
```

I used this question as a reference for making var out of files, [Variables magic and read from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577542/variables-magic-and-read-from-file). I want my friends to be able to use the finished product by using orca [Building a Windows executable from my Ruby app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348919/building-a-windows-executable-from-my-ruby-app). The problem I have been encountering is Watir runs Firefox by default when you use

```
agent = Watir::Browser.new
```

But not everyone uses Firefox, so this is why I created the browsertype in the file. But when I use

```
@b = "Watir::Browser.new :"+@browsertype
```

I get an error saying that the `+string` is invalid and I get the same for symbol. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can have a user defined browser type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the browser type to the initialization of the browser.:

```
@b = Watir::Browser.new @browsertype
```

This assumes that `@browsertype` is something like `'firefox'`.

Answer (score 0):

Watir accepts a small specific set of 'symbols' such as :chrome for the browser type.  If accepting input from a user I'd use a case statement to setup a variable that contains the specific symbol (:firefox, :chrome, etc) based on their input and give feedback to the user if they don't type in a value that matches what you've anticipated.

alternatively you can also use .to_sym on a string to cast it to a symbol.. so

```
@browser_type = "chrome"
@b = Watir::Browser.new @browser_type.to_sym
```